# Powering a DC to DC power supply that came without an adaptor

Tags: power-supply, dc, adapter, atx

I bought a mini [ATX DC to DC power supply on eBay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=200612491779) to use with a motherboard. Unfortunately I did not notice it came without any kind of adaptor. So what I have is basically two wires, red and black, that is supposed to connect to a "12 volt power supply". I hardly think my local gadget store sells any kind of adapter that accepts two bare wires.

Is there an adaptor for sale that is made to work with this kind of power supply?

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not show and tell.  I don't see a question here.  Everything is a statement and nothing ends with a question mark.

Comment: It does sell soldering irons though, doesn't it?

Comment: It's hard to make my question sound question-ish when someone blatantly edits away the line that was meant to show that I am indeed interested in knowing how to get this device working. I re-added a much more direct approach, please leave it be. Also, what would I solder in on to? The part where I specified my rather limited experience was also edited away, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That **LOOKS** like quite a nice power supply, and would be very useful in some circumstances.

- **IF you were wanting to operate your PC from 12 Volts DC then this is a suitable supply for you.**
- But **IF you want to operate it from AC mains you should sell / give this to somebody else and obtain a more normal power supply** - because adding a mains to 12V conversion stage will introduce extra problems that you are unlikely to want to deal with.

**Operation:**

You should be able to connect a 12V car battery or 12V DC adaptor of sufficient power output capability to operate it.
  Red connects to +12 VDC.
  Black connects to ground = -12VDC.

They say that it supplies up to 200 Watts of power.
 To supply this much power you would need say 250 Watts input.
 At 12 Volts that's about 20 Amps.
 That is a large amount of current for typical 12V supplies.
 A LARGE 12V truck battery charger may supply that.
 Many wont.
 Even at half power you would need about 10 amps - also more than most supplies are capable of.

---

**Connector**

Your motherboard needs to support the connector shown - they say it will work with any Pentium 4 motherboard but that it is specifically made for use wih mini-ITX motherboards

[image]

[image]

The power supply was apparently [sourced from here](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=200612491779).

Comment: Cars can frequently supply 150W or more (through the cigarette lighter, more directly from the battery), and most embedded systems won't be anywhere near pushing the 200W limit, so this power supply would be likely to just work in any car-mount application.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - yes. Agree. Note my - "You should be able to connect a 12V car battery or 12V DC adaptor of sufficient power output capability to operate it." That applies if you charge it in a car or out of one. Some car alternators are good for 50A+.

Comment: Ahhh, by "truck battery charger" you weren't referring to the alternator.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - I think we are on the same wavelength :-). I gained the impression he had bought it for a non automotive use so I was trying to explain the sort of size of 12V power supply that he would need. ie massive by normal standards. Even at 1/2 power it needs about 10A and most mains powered car chargers won't supply that so I said "truck battery charger". I wholly agree with you that "in car" the situation is easier - although I'd avoid trying to draw 20A from a cigarette lighter socket if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. Sorry about the confusion; In the original question I had specified that I wanted to operate it from a standard wall socket, but I forgot to put this piece of information back after someone edited it. When I bought it, I assumed I could just use a regular 12v battery eliminator. The two bare wires for connecting is above my desired difficulty level. I may very well take you up on the advice of buying a new model; I know very well these things normally come with wall socket adapters. I'll just have to examine what I buy slightly better.

Comment: @baggage_lump - If you can afford to keep it it will allow you to run a system from a  12VDC source with enough capacity. Typically as 12V "car battery" or directly from a car 12V supply (with suitable filtering to protect against spikes etc.)   This may or may not be of value to you. Many people would like to have this capability so, if it does not suit you then somebody will probably want to buy it from you.

Comment: "Red connects to +12 VDC.
Black connects to ground = -12VDC."  That doesn't sound right.

Comment: @endolith - It depends how you hold your brain :-). In the context I had just mentioned using **either** a 12V car battery or a 12v dc adaptor. These both have a + and a - terminal. Neither must be earthed, although the general convention is to ground -ve. We call the + terminal +12V without much thought. In an isolated system like this with no ground and no other supply, calling the - terminal 12V is every bit as  as valid. I agree that there is an opportunity for confusion. BUT to have said it "more precisely" would have probably reduced clarity rather have aided it. Maybe not :-)

Answer (score 0):

What peripherals are you using with the pc? I just built several ITX pc's that do not have a dvd or cd, and uses a SSD Hard drive. This kept the current down low and we were able to use 60W 12 volt power supply bricks that run on 120vac. I plan to incorporate my design of a 12 vdc UPS into the system. This would be more efficient than the standard UPS that needs to convert from 120vac. Just because you have a 200W power supply it does not mean the pc will use that much power, it will only take what it needs.

However if space and power are not an issue, then a standard 250W ATX power supply will do nicely, and probably cheaper.